# How to get a random string from an array without duplication in android studio kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

**I am trying to make a question with 4 multiple choices, I have an array of choices (including the right choice in it) and an array of four buttons. The right choice can be any choice in the array of choices, because I generate the answer randomly from the array of choices and save it in an intent and then I put it separately into one of the buttons. I have made an array of buttons so I can irritate and put a choice in it each time. I want the choices to be generated randomly in the buttons, while having the right choice too. The problem I am facing is the duplication of answers. Using the random() method in arrays is giving me a duplicate most of the time. The main question is how can I check if the random generated choice from the array is a duplicate or not. And how can I put all the 4 choices icluding the answer in the buttons randomly without duplication**

*here is the function that generates the choices in the buttons:*

```
    private fun choices(){
    
    val rightAns = intent.getStringExtra("clip")

    val buttons = ArrayList<Button>()
    

    buttons.add(ansA) // adding the buttons in the array
    buttons.add(ansB)
    buttons.add(ansC)
    buttons.add(ansD)

     // The arraylist of choices
    val choices = getArrayList("movies")
    
    // here I choose a random button and put the right answer.
    val rand = buttons.random()
    rand.text = rightAns

   
}
```

I don't know the next step after putting the right answer in a random button,
I tried making for loops and to check each time for a duplicate but my logic didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution just after posting the question

```
val choices = getArrayList("movies")
    val randomAnsButton = buttons.random()
    randomAnsButton.text = rightAns
    buttons.remove(randomAnsButton)
    choices.remove(rightAns)

    for (button in buttons){
        val randomChoice = choices.random()
        button.setText(randomChoice)
        choices.remove(randomChoice)
    }
```

so what I did was removing the random generated choice from the array after putting it in the button, *I don't know if this is the right approach or not please let me know*

Comment: This is fine but could be improved by using Sets instead of Lists for performance reasons. Sets are significantly better performing at removing items if the number of items is large.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will consider your tip!